# How to avoid bad indentation when copy lines to Jupiter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

```
print('L1 embedding ...')
    l1_reduced_emb = reducer.fit_transform(l1_emb_sample)
    # reduced representation
    print(l1_reduced_emb.shape, y_pred_sample_products.shape)
```

For example, when I copy 4 lines from a python file to a notebook, only the first line format is right. All other lines below should be aligned with the first line, but they are indented as shown.

How to keep the original format when copying to notebook?